# Help with PHP web page

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have a webpage that has a roster for World of Warcraft on it. I would like to know how do I create summary statistics for number of each Class, number of each Race, and number of each Gender. Can someone please help. The data is read in from an XML page into an array. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create count array for each of your criteria and loop all your input data. Here is how it can look:

```
$races_count = array();
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $races_count[ $person['race'] ] ++;
}

print_r($races_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using the xml functionality built into php:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Then use `foreach` loops to summarize the data.